# is 'the' necessary before 'use'?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, nouns

1. In order to shape data into valuable insights, use of statistical analytics is crucial.
2. In order to shape data into valuable insights, the use of statistical analytics is crucial.

Which sentence is correct? is 'the' necessary before 'use' in these sentences? I'm confused because I read that 'the' is used when referring to specific nouns, but since statistical analytics is not specific, do I need to use 'the'? Can both sentences be correct?

Comment: 'The' would normally be included here. You could think of it as specifying 'the use of method A' rather than B, C, D.... This question may well be put on hold as reasonable data (eg Google Ngrams comparing 'use of statistical analytics' with 'the use of statistical analytics' (by differencing)) is missing.  Results may be skewed because articles are often dropped in titles, and false positives like 'another use of statistical analytics' occur.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Even where this is not the case, reasonable research is expected (examples of "the use of statistical analytics" and "__ use of statistical analytics" from the internet; Ngrams if available {or information that they're not}).